# ReactJS map array data

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm facing an issue in ReactJS. How should I get the value from staff data.

console.log data

```
{appointments: Array(6), staff: Array(2)}
appointments: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
staff: (2) [{…}, {…}]
```

```
staff: Array(2)
0: {id: "2", category_id: null, wp_user_id: "1", attachment_id: "0", full_name: "Barbershop", …}
1: {id: "5", category_id: null, wp_user_id: "1", attachment_id: "0", full_name: "Barbershop", …}
```

react component

```
    this.state = { 
      appointmentdata:[],
   }

 componentDidMount() {
    // axios.get(`http://localhost/v1/appointments/`)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      const appointmentdata = res.data;
      console.log(appointmentdata);
      this.setState({ appointmentdata});
    })
    }

//how i should get the value of staff array fullname
          {this.state.appointmentdata.map(({ full_name }, i) => (
          <div className="full-block">
              <p key={i}>
              {full_name} //full name is not show
              </p></div>
          )
          )}
```

What should I do? Anyone help me?

Comment: Can you please post how one element looks like in your `staff` array? And probably the component code would be also helpful what you have. Thanks!

Comment: When you say console.log data, are you doing `console.log(this.state)`?

Comment: i added staff array [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7599510/norbitrial)

Comment: @MHasan assume your data is fetched from api, what's the initial state? Have you updated your state after fetching?

Comment: i hav updated you can check [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8036814/andus)

Comment: @MHasan please show us the initial state too so we can help :), also, are you not rendering any thing (probably because staffdata is an empty array) or are you encountering error (probably something wrong with the state)?

Comment: can you please write the code? [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8036814/andus)

Comment: i don't understand .can you please write the code?  [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7959497/rob-bailey)

Comment: Your code looks fine so far but it's missing the description of what exact problem you have (I remember you did and you removed it accidentally when you edit the post). Please describe your problem so we can provide a solution.

Comment: i updated the code you can check [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8036814/andus)

Answer (score 0):

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma617476116433166?file=index.js)

When you do this:

```js
this.setState({ appointmentdata });
```

You're creating a new attribute named after "appointmentdata" inside your state object. So, you should grab your data like this:

```js
{this.state.appointmentdata.staff.map(({ full_name }, i) =>
  <div className="full-block">
    <p key={i}>{full_name}</p>
  </div>
)}
```

If you don't want this additional level on your state, you can destruct the data in the `setState`:

```js
this.setState({ ...appointmentdata });
```

But, what you should be doing is:

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    appointments: [],
    staff: []
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  axios.get(`http://localhost/v1/appointments/`)
    .then(res => this.setState({...res.data}));
}


render() {
  return (
    <>
      {this.state.staff && this.state.staff.map(({ full_name }, i) => (
        <div key={i} className="full-block">
          <p>{full_name}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6433166/julianobrasil)

Comment: can you please help me [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6433166/julianobrasil)

Comment: I've added a demo in my answer and some defensive code.

Comment: ur code output is not show [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6433166/julianobrasil])

Comment: Yes, it is. Open the console and click on the button and you'll see your unmount message. As a matter of fact, I'll suggest in my answer what I think you're trying to do instead of trying to fix what you've written in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how to map over your props and/or state:

https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/oNjyaNM

```js
function MyTable(props) {
  //console.log(props);
  const initState = props.staff || [];
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(initState);

  return (
    <table>
      <tr key={"header"}>
        {Object.keys(state[0] || {}).map((key) => (
          <th>{key}</th>
        ))}
      </tr>
      {state.map((item) => (
        <tr key={item.id}>
          {Object.values(item || {}).map((val) => (
            <td>{val}</td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
  );
}

const myStaff = [
  {id: "2", category_id: null, wp_user_id: "1", attachment_id: "0", full_name: "Barbershop" },
  {id: "5", category_id: null, wp_user_id: "1", attachment_id: "0", full_name: "Barbershop" }
];

ReactDOM.render(<MyTable staff={myStaff} />, document.getElementById("target"));
```

```css
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Here is your specific example (functional component):

```js
function MyStaff(props) {
  //console.log(props);
  const initState = props.staff || [];
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(initState);
  //console.log(state);

  return (
    <div>
      {
        state.map(item => (
          <div key={item.id}>
            <p>{item.full_name}</p>
          </div>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
}

const staffData = [
  {id: "2", category_id: null, wp_user_id: "1", attachment_id: "0", full_name: "Barbershop" },
  {id: "5", category_id: null, wp_user_id: "1", attachment_id: "0", full_name: "Barbershop" }
];

ReactDOM.render(<MyStaff staff={staffData} />, document.getElementById("target"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Here is your specific example as a Class component:

```js
class MyStaff extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      staff: this.props.staff || []
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.staff.map(item => (
            <div key={item.id}>
              <p>{item.full_name}</p>
            </div>
          ))
        }
      </div>
    );
  }  
}

const staffData = [
  {id: "2", category_id: null, wp_user_id: "1", attachment_id: "0", full_name: "Barbershop" },
  {id: "5", category_id: null, wp_user_id: "1", attachment_id: "0", full_name: "Barbershop" }
];

ReactDOM.render(<MyStaff staff={staffData} />, document.getElementById("target"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: can you add these lines in my code [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9792594/alex-l)

Comment: plz help me [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9792594/alex-l)

Comment: check my updated answer, should hopefully help you. Remember you need a div (or fragment or another tag) around all of your mapped components too.

Comment: added a class based component example now too